# The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. "Unable to load DLL 'git2-572e4d8':

Tags: libgit2sharp

We are also getting the same exception. We are using Azure Function and using v0.26.0 of LibGit2Sharp. This exception arises when we are debugging our azure function using Azure CLI debugger.

We have already tried adding 'AutoGenerateBindingRedirects true AutoGenerateBindingRedirects' to csproj file of the project but still no luck. Though it runs fine in console app but is throwing exception in Azure function.

Here is the stack trace:
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_repository_open(git_repository*& repository, FilePath path)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options, RepositoryRequiredParameter requiredParameter)
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path)
at GitDeploy.GitRepositoryManager.UpdateRepository()
at CrmSolution.RepositoryHelper.TryPushToRepository(String committerName, String committerEmail, String authorEmail, SolutionFileInfo solutionFile, String solutionFilePath, HashSet`1 hashSet)
at CrmSolution.RepositoryHelper.TryUpdateToRepository(String solutionUniqueName, String committerName, String committerEmail, String authorEmail)

Comment: Ever resolve this?